how to mint compressed NFT using bubblegum inside solana program (rust)
I'm going to write a solana program (rust, probably anchor) which mints NFTs to a collection using Bubblegum standard.
I noticed most guide use JS/TS to mint cNFTs with bubblegum, but I need to do this in Rust in this case.
Right now I'm looking at https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/mpl-bubblegum rust crate but not sure this is going to work for me.
Would appreciate any help or guide on this.
Thanks
Update:


You can use reference these example programs:
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/compression/cnft-vault
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/compression/cnft-burn

I really appreciate your shared info, but I see it doesn't have the minting feature explained.
I updated the post with my current progress referncing your link, kindly take a look.

here is another reference: https://github.com/ZYJLiu/anchor-compressed-nft/blob/master/programs/anchor-compressed-nft/src/lib.rs#L56

you will also need to use an rpc that suppports cnft indexing, helius free tier is a good option

thank you for the info, it looks like a good example.
but it throws error when I try to run the test.
I shared it in the post.
some guides say it's related with stack space and tells to optimized instruction accouts, but I don't see much space to optimize accounts in this case.
I also try to skip 'create tree' method call, by implementing it with web3 in test,
but same thing happens with minting cNFT.
one funny thing is, I succeeded to run first time when I executed, and starts failing since the second time, even I try with the fresh codebase from the link you shared

I discovered that the test goes through with the original program id, and fails if I replace it with another one after rebuilding the program.
what a strange dependency

is it reference elsewhere, besides Anchor.toml and lib.rs?
